# Add variable to a string in Twig

Tags: twig

I am trying to modify the value 7 in the following twig code:

```
{{ "now"|date_modify("+7 days")|date("Y/m/d") }}
```

The above works fine, but if I try this I get an error:

```
{{ "now"|date_modify("+" . user.days . " days")|date("Y/m/d") }}
```

Is it possible to edit the number of days dynamically in twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `~` to concatenate like this :

```
{{ "now"|date_modify("+" ~ user.days ~ " days")|date("Y/m/d") }}
```

Comment: @Shaun, you're welcome and thank's for your return. :)